# Getting Heuristic of 2 coordinates for A* algorithm

Tags: c#, path-finding

For my school project im making a 2D tile map with A* algorithm to find shortest path through obstacles. I have used a formula to get heuristic score for the next tiles from http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/06/a-pathfinding-algorithm.html

This is the function for getting heuristic

```
    public static int geth(int cx, int cy, int ex, int ey)
    {
        //cx = current position x
        //cy = current position y
        //ex = end (goal) position x
        //ey = end (goal) position y

        int c = 14;
        int d_min = Math.Min(cx - ex, cy - ey);
        int d_max = Math.Max(cx - ex, cy - ey);
        int h = c * d_min + (d_max - d_min);
        if (h < 0) //make h positive in case it's negative
        {
            h = h * -1;
        }

        return h;
    }
```

This works when start point is higher on y-axis than end point, but doesn't find the most efficient path when start is lower on y-axis.

I've added a console version of my problem. The most efficient should be diagonally going up, but it takes a wrong path.

(blue 'C' are the nodes checked, green 'P' path made, red 'N' still to be checked, others are not yet reached)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked article, I see this algorithm:
[image]

The pipe symbols `|` around the differences are the [absolute value function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value), and this is represented in C# as `Math.Abs`.

Distance does not have a sign attached to it. `cx - ex` will be negative when `ex` is larger than `cx` (and likewise with `cy - ey`) which can cause your `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` to choose the wrong dimension for `d_min` and `d_max`. You should use `Math.Abs` to remove the sign from the quantities being compared.

e.g.

```
    int d_min = Math.Min(Math.Abs(cx - ex), Math.Abs(cy - ey));
```

(And likewise for `d_max`.)